# Change document root in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I have tried every possible solution to change the document root on ubuntu to my new site but nothing works. I have changed the setting in available sites default file (both document root and directory root) to my new directory housing the website or creating a new available sites file pointing to my web directory and switching the site through  `a2ensite`  and  `a2dissite`  commands. But still it goes to the same default page

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed that :

1. Install webmin
2. From webmin goto servers->Apache webserver
3. Edit the default "virtual host" :

   - handle all connections
   - add your doc-root
   - use httpd.conf file ..

Once done do a server restart from webmin or the command line:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```